# Inverse of the Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Reviewing the abstract algebra, I compared the inverse of mapping the ring, group(homomorphism) and vector spaces(Linear map). So this question came across my mind, suddenly.

Here the $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the field, $F$

For linear mapping, $T : V \to W$ with $T(v_1) = w_1$

Then, Is the $v_1 \in kerT + v_2$ for any $v_2$ ? (Here the $T(v_2) = w_1$)

Well... Focusing the specific case like the $T$ is invertible, The above is surely true, I thought. But the problem is What if the case the $T$ is not invertible? Is it holds for general case including $T$ is not invertible?

Thanks.

p.s.) Any proof always welcome. In my book there aren't any comments with regard to it.

Comment: $T(v_1-v_2)=0$ so $v_1-v_2 \in ker (T)$.

Comment: To clarify, your question is $T(v_1)=T(v_2)$ implies that $v_1\in \ker T + v_2$?

Comment: @DavidP, Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the kernel of a linear mapping $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a subspace of $V$.

In particular, $T$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\ker T$ is the nullspace $\{0\}$.
In the latter case, $T(v_1)=w_1=T(v_2)$ means that $v_1=v_2$.

In general, however, $T(v_1)=w_1=T(v_2)$ means that $v_1-v_2\in\ker T$ or $v_2\in v_1+\ker T$.